# Zookeeper integration with .Net c# getting error while fetching node

Tags: c#, .net, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I am new to Zookeeper, I am working on a project in .Net c# console application and pass credentials So i made below changes for passing credentials. and it shows status as connected but just after connected  i try to access first root node i am getting exception.
We are using Zookeeper latest Version : 3.9.1 and for .Net integration
I am using below packages for Zookeeper integration with .Net
[image]
Please help/suggest  if  these packages for .net and Zookeeper version are compatible or not as last checkin was in 2019 for zookeeper (https://github.com/shayhatsor/zookeeper).

[image]

[image]

**Exception Details ==>**

**Message **: [image: -124 is not a defined value for enum type org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException+Code]

[image]

I tried to debug the code but
Before exception status is showing as connected ZooKeeper.States.CONNECTED
Exception I am getting is whenever existsAsync code is executed.